# From bounded moments to probabilities of an interval

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-problem

For any random variable (say $X$)on $\mathbb{R}$ is there a way to connect the measure of an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ (some $\mu(I)$) from some information (bounds?) on the moments of $X$ say $\mathbb{E}[\vert X \vert ^r]$?

Comment: So do you want some concentration inequalities like Chebyshev's Inequality? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality

Comment: For an arbitrary interval if I want to somehow show that $\mu$ of it can be arbitrarily high then will Chebyshev help?